# MonoDevelop error

Tags: mono

I developed one [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) project which runs perfectly on MonoDevelop in Windows, but it throws a compiler error like `System.Services DLL error`. The exact error message is

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What could be the problem?

Comment: the type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System'. Are you missing any assembly reference ? if i need to add some reference, how to ?

Comment: can you edit your post and include the build error above?

Answer (score 1):

System.ServiceModel is provided by the System.ServiceModel.dll assembly. You should be able to choose this by right clicking on the "Refrences" folder in the solution tree and choosing "Edit".

You should also take note that [WCF on mono](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF) is not 100% complete. It may however do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yοu can add the missing assemblies by using below command in linux:

`gacutil -i System.Data.dll`

and adding during compile time is:

`gmcs filename -r:System.Data.dll`